# Authorize.Net errors after updating to Civi 4.7

Tags: civicontribute, drupal, 4.7, authorize.net

I updated from 4.6 to 4.7.7 yesterday and if a guest user comes to our site to register they receive the following errors:

> Notice: Undefined index: user_name in CRM_Core_Payment_AuthorizeNet->__construct() (line 55 of .../civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/AuthorizeNet.php).
>   Notice: Undefined index: password in CRM_Core_Payment_AuthorizeNet->__construct() (line 56 of .../civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/AuthorizeNet.php).

However, if I am logged in to my drupal site, I do not receive these errors. Any idea why this is happening? I went into the Admin > System > Payment Processors and there's no place for user_name or password. I'm guessing they are looking for a drupal username; however we do not require login to register or donate using civi.

We are using Civi 4.7.7 on Drupal 7.x (can't remember which version).

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**
This happens only for the payment processor

so please try to delete the payment processor and uninstall the payment processor extension if you have any

Then install the payment processor extension and add a payment processor again

Then clear all your cache and try again